# How to get the count of nested ng-repeat items

Tags: angularjs, indexing, filter, count, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I hide nested ng-repeat blocks if they return no values once filtered? "[if no items in filtered set hide]"

```
           <div ng-repeat="thisCategory in Categories">
                <div class="panel panel-default" ng-hide="filterResult[$index].length == 0">
                    <div class="panel-body" [if no items in filtered set hide]>

                        <div>
                            </h1>{{thisCategory.Title}}</h1>
                        </div>

                        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">  
                            <tr ng-repeat="app in (filterResult = (apps | filter:search ))">
                                <td>
                                    {{app.Title}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I just do like `ng-hide="!Categories.length"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like;

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" 
    ng-show="(filterResult[$index] = (apps | filter:search )).length">  
    <tr ng-repeat="app in (filterResult[$index] = (apps | filter:search ))">
        <td>
            {{app.Title}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am unable to get the $index length. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance of a Plunker?